# Using Multiprocessing with Modules

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am writing a module such that in one function I want to use the Pool function from the multiprocessing library in Python 3.6. I have done some research on the problem and the it seems that you cannot use if `__name__=="__main__"` as the code is not being run from main. I have also noticed that the python pool processes get initialized in my task manager but essentially are stuck.

So for example:

```
class myClass()
    ...
    lots of different functions here
    ...
    def multiprocessFunc()
        do stuff in here
    def funcThatCallsMultiprocessFunc()
        array=[array of filenames to be called]
        if __name__=="__main__":
            p = Pool(processes=20)
            p.map_async(multiprocessFunc,array)
```

I tried to remove the `if __name__=="__main__"` part but still no dice. any help would appreciated.

Comment: Put the `if __name__...` part outside of your class definition for a start.

Comment: The problem, with doing that is that I want the pools to be initialized in that specific function.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your have just missed out a `self.` from your code. I should think this will work:

```
class myClass():
    ...
    # lots of different functions here
    ...
    def multiprocessFunc(self, file):
        # do stuff in here
    def funcThatCallsMultiprocessFunc(self):
        array = [array of filenames to be called]
        p = Pool(processes=20)
        p.map_async(self.multiprocessFunc, array)  #added self. here
```

Now having done some experiments, I see that `map_async` could take quite some time to start up (I think because multiprocessing creates processes) and any test code might call `funcThatCallsMultiprocessFunc` and then quit before the `Pool` has got started.

In my tests I had to wait for over 10 seconds after `funcThatCallsMultiprocessFunc` before calls to `multiprocessFunc` started. But once started, they seemed to run just fine.

This is the actual code I've used:

**MyClass.py**

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

import time
import string

class myClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.result = None
    def multiprocessFunc(self, f):
        time.sleep(1)
        print(f)
        return f
    def funcThatCallsMultiprocessFunc(self):
        array = [c for c in string.ascii_lowercase]
        print(array)
        p = Pool(processes=20)
        p.map_async(self.multiprocessFunc, array, callback=self.done)
        p.close()
    def done(self, arg):
        self.result = 'Done'
        print('done', arg)
```

**Run.py**

```
from MyClass import myClass

import time

def main():
    c = myClass()
    c.funcThatCallsMultiprocessFunc()
    for i in range(30):
        print(i, c.result)
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I tried this and the error was that the function was missing a parameter self.

Comment: Yes, note the use of `self` as parameters to the methods in my answer.

Comment: No I added the selfs where you stated to add them and still got that error. I don't think this is a matter of self because once I do this without multiprocessing it works fine.

Comment: All I'm saying is that I've run tests with similar, but not identical, code and everything works. I'll see if I can post that code . . .

Answer (score 0):

The `if __name__=='__main__'` construct is an import protection. You want to use it, to stop `multiprocessing` from running your setup on import.

In your case, you can leave out this protection in the class setup. Be sure to protect the execution points of the class in the calling file like this:

```
def apply_async_with_callback():
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=30)
    for i in range(z):
        pool.apply_async(parallel_function, args = (i,x,y, ), callback = callback_function)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print "Multiprocessing done!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    apply_async_with_callback()
```

Comment: This module is being called in another program, namely jupyter notebook, will this work?